# Hardcoding HLSL Shader

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, shader, hlsl

I have a shader written in HLSL that I do not want the user to be able to access. Is there a way I can go about compiling from a section of memory. The problem is that the following function accepts an `LPCSTR` in order to use a `.fx` file as input:

```
    HRESULT D3DXCreateEffectFromFile(
  _In_   LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 pDevice,
  _In_   LPCTSTR pSrcFile,
  _In_   const D3DXMACRO *pDefines,
  _In_   LPD3DXINCLUDE pInclude,
  _In_   DWORD Flags,
  _In_   LPD3DXEFFECTPOOL pPool,
  _Out_  LPD3DXEFFECT *ppEffect,
  _Out_  LPD3DXBUFFER *ppCompilationErrors
);
```

I need something more along the lines of void* or at least some way to compile from a block of memory. Other than just saving the data to a file, compiling, and deleting the file, is there a way to do this?

```
wchar_t* shaderCode = L"//Poorly formatted shader code goes here";
```

I want to be able to literally compile from the above section of memory. How can this be done?

Comment: What is your development environment? (Microsoft Visual Studio provides resource files)

Comment: Yes, microsoft visual studio indeed. I'm going to look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. the D3DXCreateEffect function. Creates an effect from an ASCII or binary effect description.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb172763(v=vs.85).aspx

Might also check out D3DX10CompileFromMemory..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb310587(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Wow, I feel really stupid. Thanks so much, this is perfect :)

Comment: I'll accept it as soon as I can, problem is you answered too fast ;)

Comment: @JosephPla: Note that this does *not* prevent a user from being able to access the shader. They can always yank it from your executable, though obviously it requires more effort. But it requires *less* effort than figuring out what compression your pack files use and decoding it from that.

Comment: @NicolBolas alright, thanks alot. I'll definitely keep that in mind.